# SHAREPoint Data transfer

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint

I had created a multi site SharePoint application using MOSS 2007. My hard drive went south.  However, I was able to make an Acronis Image of the drive.  I have all the SQL 2005 Server files.  I have rebuilt the SharePoint Environment Using Win2k3 Enterprise Server, SQL 2005 Server, WSS 3.0 SP2, and MOSS 2007.  I don't want to rebuild the entire site over again.

The original site was in a laptop environment.  The new infrastructure is running on a Dell 2970 server.

I was able to restore the SQL Server files from the Acronis image to a USB drive and a DVD.  Is there a way to salvage the SQL databases/data to the new server so Sharepoint can access them?

Comment: I'll recommend asking this on http://serverfault.com as they are the IT experts :) But essentially you want to reinstall SharePoint on the server and attach the content database to the new installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Create a new web application on your newly built SharePoint Server.
2. From Central Admin site, select content database. Select and remove the content database of this new site created in step 1.
3. Frpm SQL Server Management Strudio create new database with same name as that of your 'salvaged' content database.
4. Then restore database from your 'salvaged' content database file. Choose 'overwrite' from options..
5. Back to your Central Admin site, select 'Add Content database' to the new web application you created in step 1 and specify the name of the restored database.
6. Repeat the process for each web application.